# How to make a Stream time out after x seconds without reading/writing?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I'm copying a `Stream` **a** to another `Stream` **b** over a network.

I'm doing this using `a.CopyToAsync(b)`.

Sometimes, I've observed that a copy gets stuck for some reason and no bytes are transferred. I would like to restart the copy operation if this happens.

I need to implement some kind of timeout mechanism so, whenever **a** or **b**, or both, don't read/write for `x` seconds, a TimeoutException will be thrown (triggering the restart mechanism).

How can I do this?

My current attempt is to wrap the original **input stream** (**a**) in this class:

```
public class ReadTimeoutStream: Stream
{
    private readonly Stream inner;

    public ReadTimeOutStream(Stream stream)
    {
        inner = stream;
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        inner.Flush();
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return Observable.Start(() => inner.Read(buffer, offset, count)).Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ReadTimeout)).Wait();
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return inner.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        inner.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        inner.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override int ReadTimeout { get; set; }

    public override bool CanTimeout => true;

    public override bool CanRead => inner.CanRead;

    public override bool CanSeek => inner.CanSeek;

    public override bool CanWrite => inner.CanWrite;

    public override long Length => inner.Length;

    public override long Position
    {
        get => inner.Position;
        set => inner.Position = value;
    }
}
```

So I do

```
var wrappedStream = new ReadTimeoutStream(a);
wrappedStream .CopyToAsync(b)
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

How should I proceed?